# Determining whether an existing OpenShift app is scalable

Tags: openshift

When creating an OpenShift application, one can specify whether or not it is scalable. Application scalability immutable. How do I determine whether or not an existing application is scalable?

I cannot see any information concerning this in the application details online or in the documentation, and I cannot find an appropriate rhc command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `rhc apps` command, and look for a line that starts with "Scaling"

```
haproxy-1.4 (Web Load Balancer)
  -------------------------------
    Gears: Located with ruby-2.0

  ruby-2.0 (Ruby 2.0)
  -------------------
    Scaling: x2 (minimum: 2, maximum: 4) on medium gears

  mysql-5.5 (MySQL 5.5)
  ---------------------
    Gears:          1 large
    Connection URL: mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/
    Database Name:  stage
    Password:       xxxxxxx
    Username:       xxxxxxx
```

Comment: And if there is no scaling information, I assume this means that the app is not scalable?

Comment: Correct, if Scaling is not mentioned, then it is not enabled.